# Error:java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

Tags: android

Al momento de presionar play en android studio
[image: les dejo una imagen]

La verdad no se donde esta el dilema ya que no especifica mucho ...

Gradle

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hp14.iteracion2"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    compile 'de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.5@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile files('libs/glide-3.7.0.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
}
```

Comment: Hola Felix, ¿has probado con Clean Project? Si no te funciona con esto, prueba a eliminar el fichero .gradle, cierra Android Studio y vuelve a abrirlo para que se vuelva a generar.

Comment: Holla @DevCodeG, no amigo, sin embargo he borrado la carpeta .gradle del proyecto y se ha arreglado, como muestra en la respuesta abajo

Comment: Vale @Felix Beeb, me alegro amigo. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mí me apareció este error hace un tiempo cuando se me fue la luz mientras se abría el proyecto.

En mi caso era que el fichero `gradle` se había vuelto corrupto. Eliminando la carpeta `gradle` del proyecto, el proyecto volvió a funcionar sin ningún error ya que `Android Studio` la vuelve a generar cuando inicias el proyecto.

Esta carpeta la puedes encontrar dentro de la carpeta en la que tengas almacenada tu aplicación.

Comment: Gracias, ha funcionado !